# How to set HTML5 video height and width in the same time?

Tags: css, html

This is the effect that I want to achieve:

[image]

But I tried code:

```
video {height :100%; width: auto}
video {width: auto; height: 100%}
```

It's useless:

Image with auto-width:

[image]

Image with auto-height:

[image]

So how can I do that? Thanks!

Comment: I'm confused - the second screenshot seems to do what you wanted?

Comment: @roryok Black border....

Comment: I dont follow the issue?

Comment: I know it's really silly. But have you tried just setting both to 100%. That should work...

Comment: @AndyHolmes the second has black border and the third out of border

Comment: @JoeCorby if I set height or width, the value of the other one will not work...

Comment: so you want the poster image to fill the video whatever its height or width are?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [the technique Twitter Bootstrap uses for embedding responsive media](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#responsive-embed).

Basically they use a width of 100% and a vertical padding for the height. As a vertical padding is based on the width of an element (rather than the height) this will ensure that the aspect ratio is always the same, regardless of how wide the video container is. This works well with any media, where the aspect ratio is important.

```
.embed-responsive {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.embed-responsive .embed-responsive-item,
.embed-responsive iframe,
.embed-responsive embed,
.embed-responsive object {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    border: 0;
}

// Modifier class for 16:9 aspect ratio
.embed-responsive.embed-responsive-16by9 {
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
}

// Modifier class for 4:3 aspect ratio
.embed-responsive.embed-responsive-4by3 {
    padding-bottom: 75%;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
    <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/yv-Fk1PwVeU" />
</div>
```

Comment: I tried, but seems not work. Image1: http://i.stack.imgur.com/YC7rt.png ; Image2: http://i.stack.imgur.com/1ZJ4Y.png

Comment: @zsx I can't tell from the linked images what is not as you expected. But the described solution works very well. You should narrow down your problem in the question above.